# CoreData: two level fetchRequest on addition

Tags: database, ios, core-data, fetch

I have a Core Data that stores Movies and Actors.
I get the list of movies through json. Each Movie has a cast(Actor, role)

So I have Movie, Actor, ActorRole entity.
When i receive the list of movies(each movie has a unique movieid):
- Fetch all movies currently in my database
- i create a NSSet of existingMoviesID
- i create a NSSet of newMoviesID
- i do a minus set to get all really new movies
- i loop through those newItems to add them to CoreData

This is pretty fast as i do only one fetch request.
Now it gets very slow when i want to add the cast to the database
What i do now when adding a new movie:
- get Actor ID
- create FetchReqyest for that Actor ID
- execute the FetchRequest
- if not found i add a new actor, else get the one in the CoreData
- i create the ActorRole which create the relationship between the Movie and the Actor

I think this is amazingly slow because i do one Fetch for each movie
So i am looking for better way to accomplish it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch all the existing `Actor` objects in one go by using the `IN` operator to fetch all the Actor objects with actor_ID values in an array. Like so:

```
NSPredicate *P=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"actor_ID IN %@", arrayOfIdValues];
```

That would speed up your `Actor` fetch which appears to be your bottleneck.